# C Program not going inside loop for Guess the number

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement

I have written the following code for the computer to guess what my number is, I have used switch case statement here which is inside a do while loop.

When I tried to run the program, the program doesnt go inside my loop, and I dont know how to fix it, can anyone help me out please?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()

{

printf("\n Grenze 1 - Obergrenze. ");

int min=1;

int max;

printf("\n Was ist Obergrenze? ");

scanf("%i",max);

int try=max;

int correct;

int input,i=0;


do{

    correct=max/2;
    printf("Low(1) High(2) oder Correct(3)? \n >");
    start: 
    scanf("%i",input);
    i++;
    switch (input)
    {
       case(1):
       {
        min=min;
        max=max/2;
       } break;


        case(2):
        {
        min=max/2;
        max=max;

        }break;

        case(3):
        {

        goto gotcha;
        }break;

        default:
        {
        printf("\n >");
        goto start;
        }break;

    }



}
while(i<try);



gotcha:

printf("\n Wieder gewonnen!!! Versuche - %i",i);

}
```

Comment: Please step through the program in a debugger and tell us what you see when you think it should enter the loop but doesn't.

Comment: what does that actually mean? ^^ ,im sort of new to coding.

Comment: and the while at the end is - while(i<try)

Comment: Start with stopping invoking *undefined behavior* by passing what is not a pointer and using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, in `scanf("%i",max);`.

Comment: A debugger is a basic tool of programming. Learn how to use it. A programmer without a debugger is like a doctor without a stethoscope.

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing what is not a pointer and using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, in`scanf("%i",max);`.

The same problem is in `scanf("%i",input);`.

Use unary `&` operator to pass the address to read data into like`scanf("%i",&max);` and `scanf("%i",&input);`.

Also note that you should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.